# Add div after every 4 posts then every 2 posts for a responsive loop

Tags: php, posts, loop, responsive

I'm currently working on a Wordpress loop for my index posts page. The loop displays the posts in 4 columns (each post has a width of 25%, so 4 posts on the same row), my purpose is to insert after every four posts two divs `<div style="clear:both;"></div><div style="separator"></div>`. For now it's working fine, but I don't find the way to make my PHP code responsive.

For example: when the window width is <=1100px, my posts will have a width (in my css media queries) of 50%, meaning 2 posts on the same row. So I will need to change `$counter % 4 == 0` to `$counter % 2 == 0`, to add the two divs after every two posts.

Here is the code:

```
$counter = 1;

if ( have_posts() ) :
  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'index-posts' );

    if ($counter % 4 == 0) :
      echo '<div style="clear:both;"></div><div class="news-separator"></div>';
    endif;

    $counter++;

  endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();
```

I'm a newbie in PHP, so I would really appreciate some help on that.

Thank a lot!

Comment: You can't modify the query based on resposiveness, the display should be handled better in your css

Comment: Thank you Tunji! I agree with you, but how would you add the two divs after every 4 posts, would you still use the PHP code? Or is it possible to create something similar in CSS?

Comment: your question says that part is working...is it not?

Comment: @rudtek the PHP is working, it display the divs after every 4 posts. But I can't find the way to make it work after every 2 posts when the browser window is <=1100px

Comment: Tunji is right about that.  You need to set the divs to be 50% via css when by using @media under 1100px.  Then they will load at 2 per row.  You could  also add a class to the code in the separator that it only shows over 1100px and add a 2nd if statement for every 2 that would be hidden on everything over 1100px. seeing as we cant see the actual loop code i can't suggest which divs to apply the css to.

Comment: Yes you're both right, I've modified my CSS and add a second statement in PHP for every 2 posts.

Thank you!

Comment: If you don't mind, I added my comment as an answer for you to mark answered so we can close this question.  would you mind doing that?

Comment: @MathieuPréaud, I've the same challenge. Would you mind sharing in the question the solution you found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the divs to be 50% via css when by using @media under 1100px. Then they will load at 2 per row. You could also add a class to the code in the separator that it only shows over 1100px and add a 2nd if statement for every 2 that would be hidden on everything over 1100px. seeing as we cant see the actual loop code i can't suggest which divs to apply the css to